# Cost different between elastic beanstalk and cloudformation for publishing web app to windows server

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cloudformation

If i publish web application to a Windows server with same configuration such  as Container ,instance type by using Cloudformation template and Beanstalk template ,
which approach will cost more at the end of month ?

Comment: Elastic Beanstalk is typically going to launch infrastructure components such as multiple EC2 instance (for HA), a load balancer, route 53, and more depending on your choices. Are you sure that your webapp deployed through CloudFormation is doing the same? Otherwise you're comparing apples to oranges.

Answer (score 1):

They should cost the same. EB or CFN, don't incur any cost - it is the underlying infrastructure that you provision will cost you. And *surprise* EB actually creates a CFN stack under the hood plus some wrapper scripts.

If they both spin up the exact same infrastructure, the cost will be the same. But EB does all the heavy lifting for you and gives you nice logging and easy updates. On the other hand, CFN gives you a lot more control on how you provision and configure your infrastructure.

Edit: EB is for developers or new customers whereas CFN is for more experienced people, devops folks and 'control freaks' :-)